# Print single field from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I've been trying for hours now to get the title field from the json code. Below is my php code

```
$search = $_GET['search'];

  $new = str_replace(' ', '+', $search);

  $url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=###&query=".$new;
  $json = file_get_contents($url);
  $json_data = json_decode($json, true);


  $title = $json_data->title;
  echo $title;
```

this is the var dump of the json

```
array(4) { ["page"]=> int(1) ["results"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["adult"]=> bool(false) ["backdrop_path"]=> string(32) "/4uJZvmEMX6Z6ag3bzym5exLY9wI.jpg" ["id"]=> int(65) ["original_title"]=> string(6) "8 Mile" ["release_date"]=> string(10) "2002-11-08" ["poster_path"]=> string(32) "/dXzTrKwpbLpCqn8O70FUUhNbYQT.jpg" ["popularity"]=> float(3.792332418578) ["title"]=> string(6) "8 Mile" ["vote_average"]=> float(6.2) ["vote_count"]=> int(185) } } ["total_pages"]=> int(1) ["total_results"]=> int(1) }
```

the error i keep getting is  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the docs: http://php.net/json_decode.  The 2nd parameter means that `$json_data` is an array, not an object.  `$title = $json_data['title'];`

Comment: there is no key as title in your json as it seems

Comment: For the future `echo '<pre>'.print_r($json_data, true).'</pre>';` will save you a butt-hurt amount of headaches =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
```

will return an array not object

so you need to use as

```
$json_data["title"];
```

NOTE : Your json decoded array is nested so you may need to use as in your case.

```
$json_data["results"][0]["title"];
```

Or better loop through and get the desired data.

Answer (score 0):

I just started using PHP and I THINK this might help you... but i'n not sure

```
foreach($json_data as $key => $value){
    if($key == "results"){
        $json_data2 = $value;
    }
}

foreach($json_data2 as $key => $value){
    if($key == "original_title"){
        $title = $value;
    }
}
echo $title;
```